# c programming: casting "void pointer" to point to struct

Tags: c, pointers

I'm writing this program to practice C programming, this is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct s1 {
        int i;
        void * p;
    };
static struct s1 *dmk;
int main(void) {

    int tong(int a, int b);
    int (*tinh)(int,int);

    struct s2 {
        int num;
        int (*cal)(int a, int b);
    };
    if(dmk->p == NULL)
    {
        printf("NULL ALERT\n");
    }
    struct s2 *cl = dmk->p;
    cl->cal = tong;

    tinh = ((struct s2 *)(dmk->p))->cal;
    printf("tinh 2, 4 ra %d\n",tinh(2,4));
    puts("!!!Hello World!!!"); /* prints !!!Hello World!!! */
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

int tong(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

When I compiled it, it didn't show any error or warning. But when I ran the program, the terminal told me that "core dumped" and did not show any result accept for the "NULL ALERT". Can anyone explain why I failed ? Thanks alot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(dmk->p == NULL)
```

fails as `dmk` is <strike>uninitialised</strike> initialised to `NULL`, points "no-where", so de-referencing it invokes undefined behaviour. Anything can happen afterwards.

Comment: Invoking UB by the `->` in the statement I quoted is the issue. The "*failure*" is on the coder side. @T.J.Crowder

Comment: Actually `dmk` **is** initialized, as it is a global variable. Problem: it is a _null pointer_.

Answer (score 2):

**Bottom line** is that what you're doing wrong is not assigning things to your various pointers before using them.

Your `dmk` is a global, so its initial value is `NULL`. You're never changing that value.

Later, you read `dmk->p`. You're now in Undefined Behavior (UB) territory. The program could easily have faulted right there, because you were reading from a `NULL` pointer.

Apparently it didn't, though, because you're seeing your `NULL ALERT` message, and so we continue.

Then you do this:

```
struct s2 *cl = dmk->p;
cl->cal = tong;
```

On the second line there, `cl` is completely indeterminate. It could be garbage, it could be `NULL`, whatever, because you're entered UB territory. Then you dereference it and *write to the result*. You could be trying to write anywhere. Writing to random pointers (or `NULL` pointers) tends to make core dumps and other Bad Things™ happen.

You need to actually assign values to your pointers before you use them.

Answer (score 2):

`dmk` is a global (aka. static (this is **not** related to the `static` keyword!), variable, thus it is initialized to a *null pointer*. You do not change this value, so `dkms->p` dereferences a *null pointer*, which invokes *undefined behaviour* (UB).

So from here, it is speculation, as UB means **anything can happen**.

Apparently the `printf` passes, probably because the address can be read. The following write OTOH fails, generating the system messsage.

Answer (score 1):

You don't initialize dmk in your code. That dmk->p is NULL is pure luck. Anything could happen.

You need to allocate memory for your struct using, for instance, malloc(), and initialize the members properly.

Comment: Actually `dmk` **is** initialized, as it is a global variable. Problem: it is a _null pointer_.